# Can't find path in Layout for translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So here is how my structure looks like, notice that I want to translate the "Home" :

[image]

and here is the structure I created for my .yml file:

```
  es:

  layouts:
    _header:
      home:        "HomeTranslated"
```

but it can't find and translate it. What did I do wrong? 
Please let me know if I need to include more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below:

```
 es:
  layouts:
    header:
      home: "HomeTranslated"

<%= link_to t(layouts.header.home), root_path %> # you must give the full path
```

Also take a look in this railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n?view=asciicast

I hope it helps.

Comment: :( thanks but I get this error: "undefined method `header' for :layouts:Symbol"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe specifying translation will help, try using `t('layouts._header.home')` instead of `t('home')`